# Hide table column generated in $this->table->generate() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Been in codeigniter for a while now.

I am generating data from the database and organize the view data in a table using the `$this->table->generate(records);`

It generates what is should be, but What if I want to HIDE the `id` that was selected in the query? Because whatever you selected in the `$this->db->select();` is also displayed in the table.

How to hide the `id` or prevent it from being showed in the table in the view?

Thanks in advance.

**My model is:**

```
function clist($search) {
        $config["per_page"] = 10;
        $where = "fn LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR mn LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR ln LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR suffix LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR address_common LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR address_brgy LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR address_city_prov LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR con_num LIKE '%%".$search."%%' OR date(date_created) LIKE '%%".$search."%%'";

        $this->db->select('id, CONCAT(fn," ",mn," ",ln," ",suffix) AS name,CONCAT(address_common,", ",address_brgy,", ",address_city_prov) AS address,con_num', FALSE);
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%M %d, %Y - %T') AS date_created", FALSE);

        if (!empty($search)) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
        $rows = $this->db->get('tbl_cust_info', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3))->result_array();

        $index = $this->uri->segment(3) + 1;

        foreach ($rows as $count => $row) {
            array_unshift($rows[$count], $index.'.');
            $index = $index + 1;

            $rows[$count]['name'] = anchor(base_url().'raffle/clist_details/?i='.$row['id'],$row['name']);
        } return $rows;
    }
```

**My Controller is:**

```
public function clist() {
        $data["title"] = "Customers' List";

        $this->load->library('table');

        $data["records"] = $this->raffle_model->clist($search);

        $data['thead'] = $this->table->set_heading('#','Name<br /><small>(First Name Middle Name Last Name Suffix )</small>','Address <br /><small>(House #, Bldg. #, Compound, Street, Avenue etc., Barangay, City / Province)</small>','Contact No<br />&nbsp','Date Created<br />&nbsp');
        $data['ttamplate'] =  $this->table->set_template(
            array(
                    'table_open' => 
                        '
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                                    <caption>
                                        <h3><strong>
                                            Customers
                                        </strong></h3>
                                        <small>Below are the list of customers.</small>
                                    </caption>
                        '
                ));

        $data['pagelinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view("templates/header", $data);
        $this->load->view("templates/nav", $data);
        $this->load->view("pages/cust_list", $data);
        $this->load->view("templates/footer", $data);
    }
```

**My view is:**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        if(empty($records)){
        echo '<br /><br /><br /><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center;"><strong>< < < No Customer found. > > ></strong></div>';
      }else{
          $thead;
          $ttemplate;
          echo $this->table->generate($records);
        }
      ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can modified $records with the columns you want

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all your data is coming in the $records array it's something like this

```
$this->table->generate(array) // all the array columns will be strucured as table cells.
$records = [
    array("name"=>'sid',age=>21), 
    array("name"=>'sid',age=>21), 
    array("name"=>'sid',age=>21), 
];
```

You don't want to show the age column. you can create the new Array like

```
  $displayableRecords = array();
  foreach($records as $record)
    $displayableRecords = $record['name'];
```

and passed the new array to generate table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I did like this, but no data is displaying on the table. But when I `echo $displayable_records`, there is data in it. `$displayable_records = array(); foreach ($records as $record) { $displayable_records = $record['name'];} echo $this->table->generate($displayable_records);` What did I missed? thanks again.

Comment: I have given you pseudo code  you can't literaly copy and paste it.

Comment: you have to first check $displayable_records to see it's contain appropriate data or not.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, Thanks @siddhesh.

Solve my issue with the code below. `array` gives me a very hard time.
Hope that someone will find this useful too.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
        if(empty($records)){
        echo '<br /><br /><br /><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="text-align: center;"><strong>< < < No Customer found. > > ></strong></div>';
      }else{
          foreach ($records as $record) { 
            $displayable_records = 
              array(
                '0' => $record['0'],
                'name' => $record['name'],
                'address' => $record['address'],
                'con_num' => $record['con_num'],
                'date_created' => $record['date_created']
              );
              $this->table->add_row($displayable_records);
          }
          echo $this->table->generate();
        }
      ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: @siddhesh Hahaha... Yes. thanks for you help, Still learning in programming and expanding. Thanks again...